# Random Desktop Freezes ubuntu 18,04.02

Tags: 18.04

Host: 123 Kernel: 4.18.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Machine:   CPU:  Bay-Trail J1900
           Graphics:  Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.1 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Desktop
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.8

Audio :    Realtek ALC888S

Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8119-CG PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Drives:    HDD Total Size: 64GB SSD(12% used)

Partition: ID-1: / size: 64G fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1

RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present

Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0

Comment: There is no question or problem description in your post.
Could you describe what freezes you are experiencing? Is it for a second, couple of seconds or total freeze where you have to reboot? Could it be related to some concrete application you use at that time? What is the average load on the machine when it freezes?

Comment: Desktop freeze happened at booting into the desktop and wait about 30 seconds. touch keybaord, mouse no function,
But when I press power button then press "cancel"(use touch), then touch, mouse, keyboard work again and become normal, it look like desktop refresh when press "cancel".
I do not install any application or software in Ubuntu.
The fail rate : boot 20 times occurs 1 time.
And I tried other Ubuntu 14.4.6 and 16.4.6, it would not happen the situation at the same machine.

Comment: When it freezes, do you have to press power button or would it "unfreeze" itself later?

Comment: Also, when the problem happens, could you afterward run these two commands from terminal and post output? `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame`. Please post the output to the original post, not in comments